# How to determine if GPS coordinates fall in a defined area?

Tags: gps, satellite

TLDR; I'm looking for solutions/algorithms to determine the following:

- if an arbitrary coordinate (lat/lon) resides in the area of a circle resting on the surface of the Earth
- if an arbitrary coordinate is resting along the circumference of a circle
- if the borders of two circles on a sphere intersect
- how to 'create' a circle on a sphere with an arbitrary number of coords, say 10 coords that wrap around the Earth

If you've got insight to any of those points, please help. Suggested reading/online courses are welcome as well.

---

Longer version, I'm working on a little side project to send me an alert when a satellite passes in view and is in a good spot/time to actually be seen. At the moment I have user coords and I can increment the satellite's position to grab its position at a point in time, see image 2; the problem I am facing with this is the 'gap' between the coordinates I calculated along the orbit, I don't know how to define the relationship between all of those points.

To that end, I'd like to create one circle on the face of the Earth, using the satellite's ground path during one of its orbits, I know the circle won't match the orbit perfectly but I'm just looking for 'close enough'. And then create another circle around the user's coord, out to their horizon. From there I'll need to determine if the circles intersect. If they do intersect I'll then need to see where along the projected orbital path is closest to the user. There's a couple other factors at play here but, once the nearest point is found the alert can go out.

Using the first picture, points A, B & C all fall on the satellites projected orbital path in lat/lon coords. A is just a point along said path, B is the point that is both within the user's horizon and closest to the user and C is one of the intersection points between the orbit circle and the user's horizon.

[image: Orbit path through an area]
[image: Noncontinuous Orbital Path]

Comment: Which language and library are you using?

Comment: node.js along with the satellite.js library for orbital and GPS data.